# does the "installs" number given in the playstore for an app mean installed on the phone right now or just downloaded?

Tags: google-play

for each app in the playstore, it says how many installs there are. Eg. depending on the app the category could be something like 10k-50k or for popular apps such as FB it is in the millions.

I am wondering what "installs" means. Is it that the apps are actually installed on the users phones right now or would a download/install and deleting the app 5 min later also count towards this number??

Tried to google this but without much success.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: The number shown on Play Store is Total Install ( not active installs). You can view active install / Total installs on google play store admin console

Comment: thanks - I am looking at apps in general so I do not have access to the admin console of the developer. research suggests that up to 75% of apps are deleted within 5 min of installs. if that is true then it would be possible to estimate active users (even though it probably varies depending on the type of app).

Comment: yes it's a an issue with developers, retention of users is problem across apps. It's more tough for games compare to apps. But not sure about 75%. it varies from apps to apps ( also games vs apps vs domain , country etc )